# Cube in tableau software

Tags: postgresql, pentaho, tableau-api, olap-cube, mondrian

I have created cube multidimensional database using mondrian and pentaho 
schema workbench.   I want to know if i can read this cube from tableau software reporting tool any paths to follow pleas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tableau doesn't support Mondrian OLAP cubes at the moment. If the data source is ODBC 3.0 compliant, you may be able to connect to the cube data source using ODBC drivers. Check this [community](https://community.tableau.com/message/465504#465504) post.